# How to convert php html output to pdf online?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I found this library to convert `HTML` to `PDF`: `dompdf`.

The example source code looks like this:

```
<?php   
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $html =
      '<html><body>'.
      '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
      'templating system.</p>'.
      '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
?>
```

Is there a way to import a `PHP` output into this code?

Or is there a better way to convert a PHP output to PDF?

Comment: "Import a PHP output"? You could just add it to the `$html` string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Output Buffers to achieve this as well. I've used this with DOMPDF in the past.

```
/* Use output buffer capture */
ob_start();
require_once "Renderer.php";
$layoutHTML = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

$layoutHTML will have the processed HTML.

And then you can use DOMPDF the way you've described in your question

```
 $dompdf->load_html($html);
```

Careful that this can chew a lot of memory (depending on the problem of course).

Comment: The ob_start() code worked perfectly. But it looks like the DOMPDF library doesn't work whit big pages. I think I'll better send the output in an HTML file using the code you provided me.

Answer (score 0):

The `$dompdf->load_html($html);` method is simply taking a string argument.

The `$html` variable could be populated using `file_get_contents` from a website:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

You could also read a file:

```
$html = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
```

Or you could use output control:

```
ob_start();
include 'my.awesome.template.html';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```